# Apache POI Hyperlink does not open in Microsoft Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to create hyperlink using apache poi which points to a URL. This URL returns a file which is a PDF file. I have written the code as below to create a link

```
HSSFHyperlink link = new HSSFHyperlink(HSSFHyperlink.LINK_URL);
link.setAddress(cellValue);
cell.setHyperlink(link);
cell.setCellValue(cellValue);
```

I am getting the link in Excel sheet properly and able to open the link in every editor except Microsoft Excel. It throws an error Cannot open the link. I am able to open the link in Google Sheets, Open Office etc.

Please help me out as I am not sure this is a known issue or something I am missing

Comment: Did you make sure you're using the latest version of Apache POI to generate the file?

Comment: I am currently using 3.9 build and latest is 3.10. I will try with that version. I can see some of the fixes in change log but nothing related to my issue

Comment: i tried exactly the same code, i run, then i open the resulting .xls, and at the beginning, it looks like a usual text. But! If you click to the cell twice (to start editing cell value), then you click somewhere else, and, when editing cell value is finished (even if you haven't even touchedthe keyboard, just clicking IN and OUT of the cell), the link will automatically become clickable, blue, underlined, and leads correctly to its address. P.S. I'm using POI 3.10

Answer (score 1):

If you export excel in .xls format then use HSSFHyperlink. For .xlxs use XSSFHyperlink class. It is working in apache poi 3.10

```
cell.setCellValue("URL Link");
HSSFHyperlink link1 =(HSSFHyperlink)createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_URL);
link1.setAddress("http://www.google.com/");
cell.setHyperlink((HSSFHyperlink) link1);
cell.setCellStyle(hlink_style);
```

Comment: If you export excel in .xls format then use HSSFHyperlink. For .xlxs use XSSFHyperlink class. It is working in apache poi 3.10

Comment: please add your above comment to your answer body

Answer (score 0):

I created Hyperlinks using [this Example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/HyperlinkExample.java). I had to change to `.xlsx` to `.xls` to be able to open the file in MS Excel 2010 but the links are working fine.

But your code looks good as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the problem with Apache poi. If you have the hyperlinks that require login details, cookie will not be set in the excel which will lead to login page again. Hence, I tried working around by setting the cookies.

First I tried creating a URL along with the user details encoded
Once in excel, if you click on the URL, I opened another page which will verify the user details and redirects to the required page.